# Is it possible to reset a Jenkins build parameter such that 'Rebuild' or 'Retry' uses the new value?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job with the parameter `PULL_REQUEST_ID` that defaults to `*`. It's used to get the branch of a Stash pull request. During the build, the exact pull request id is known. I can reset the `PULL_REQUEST_ID` environment variable but when hitting 'Rebuild', the `PULL_REQUEST_ID` parameter is still set to `*`. Is there a way to get Jenkins to 'remember' the reset value?

Answer (score 1):

With the Groovy Plugin:

```
import hudson.model.ParametersAction
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue

build.replaceAction(
    new ParametersAction(
        new StringParameterValue('PULL_REQUEST_ID', '1234')))
```

If there are other build parameters, be sure to preserve them.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for this [Rebuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin). Try install it. It allows you to rebuild a parametrized build without entering the parameters again.It will also allow you to edit the parameters before rebuilding.

First, you set a parameter named `PULL_REQUEST_ID` and set it to default value `*` and trigger a build.
[image]

[image]

After the build, click the build result from `Build History`. Then click the `Rebuild` button from the left sidebar. You will get a Rebuild view like below screenshot shows and it can be edited to whatever you want. After you edit it, click `Rebuild` button. And next time, once you do the same steps as above, Jenkins will show the new value here rather than the default `*`. 
[image]

Comment: We have the Rebuild Plugin installed. Hitting rebuild will use the default value, not the reset value.